# My button is showing div, but how to hide div after second click?

Tags: togglebutton

Okay. So I've done button which shows four more items (divs). Can somebody help me how to toggle this button? I want hide this four items by clicking for the second time on the same button. 
Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('four-more-portfolio-items').style.display = "block";}
</script>
```

And HTML:

```
<div id="four-more-portfolio-items" style="display: none;">
......
......
......
</div>
```

Comment: Do you accept jQuery or only pure javascript?

Comment: I can accept everything! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `toggle()` method for this task.

```
$("#button_id").click(function() {
    $("#four-more-portfolio-items").toggle();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 1):

Script:

```
<script>
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById("four-more-portfolio-items");
    if(x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="four-more-portfolio-items" style="display: none;">
......
......
......
</div>

<button onClick="showDiv()">Show Div</button>
```

At start of program div isn't showing, but after one click button it is.